# yahoo.co.jp login using php curl?

Tags: php, cookies, curl, authentication, yahoo

I want to login yahoo.co.jp website using php and curl. i have already tried yahoo.com. its working very good. but when i am using the same format to login in yahoo.co.jp. But its not working. its going capcha verification.

[image]

I am trying many ways but its not working my code is given below.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

//$php_userid = 'username';
//$php_password ='password';

Example login
$php_userid = 'jpnathanstock';
$php_password ='somepwpw!2345';



$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; // Please set your Cookie File path

$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'wb'); 
fclose($fp);
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.2; ja-jp; SonyEricssonSO-01C Build/3.0.D.2.79) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
$reffer = "http://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login?.lg=jp&.intl=jp&logout=1&.src=www&.done=http://www.yahoo.co.jp";

// log out.
$LOGINURL = "http://us.ard.yahoo.com/SIG=12hoqklmn/M=289534.5473431.6553392.5333790/D=mail/S=150500014:HEADR/Y=YAHOO/EXP=1135053978/A=2378664/R=4/SIG=133erplvs/*http://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login?logout=1&.done=http://auctions.yahoo.co.jp/&.src=ym&.lg=us&.intl=us"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


//1. Get first login page to parse hash_u,hash_challenge

$LOGINURL = "https://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login?"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

preg_match_all("/name=\".u\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $loginpage_html, $arr_hash_u);
preg_match_all("/name=\".challenge\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $loginpage_html, $arr_hash_challenge);

 $hash_u = $arr_hash_u[1][0];
 $hash_challenge = $arr_hash_challenge[1][0];



//.tries=1&.src=auc&.last=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.co.jp%2Fconfig%2Fedit_auc&promo=&.intl=jp&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=cq4ce2ov02mdi&.v=0&.fUpdate=Y&hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fuser.auctions.yahoo.co.jp%2Fjp%2Fshow%2Fmystatus&login=********&passwd=***********
// 2- Post Login Data to Page https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?

$LOGINURL = "https://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login";

$POSTFIELDS = '.tries=1&.src=auc&.hash=&.last=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.co.jp%2Fconfig%2Fedit_auc&promo=&.intl=jp&.bypass=&.partner=&.u='.$hash_u.'&.v=0&.fUpdate=Y&.challenge='.$hash_challenge.'&.hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fuser.auctions.yahoo.co.jp%2Fjp%2Fshow%2Fmystatus&login='.$php_userid.'&passwd='.$php_password;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
print_r($result);
exit;
?>
```

Please guide me. What's wrong my code. Advice me anyone..

Comment: I'm sorry I can't read the error message, can you translate it to English so we can help ?

Comment: you are not posting at all these variables **$php_userid = 'jpnathanstock';
$php_password ='somepwpw!2345';**

Comment: @DarkWish they're actually there, in the `$POSTFIELDS` variable

Answer (score 3):

You have a lingering `http://us.ard.yahoo.com` in the first `$loginurl`, it should probably be a `*.co.jp`, you need to check the docs to know the correct URL to use.

Another issue might be that you forgot to change the URL signature when you toggle between `.co.jp` and `.com`

**EDIT**

When i looked a bit more into your code, i noticed you immediately open then close the cookie jar, which won't work, you also open it with write binary `wb` flag, that's not needed. that's why you have an empty cookie.

what you need to do is

```
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; // Please set your Cookie File path
$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'w');
```

Then at the very end of your script you can close the cookie file

```
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Well this error might mean that something doesn't match in the host name OR the signature, can you show me the contents of `$cookie` and the final `$LOGINURL` ? also what's the contents of the final `$result` that you're echoing ?

Comment: That might be a hint on whats going on, can you revert back to the .com version and check what the cookie contains ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally , from my research it is not possible to bypass the yahoo login in oauth, as the login program is keep updating. And it is oauth, what you really need is

1. implement a link for the user to login
2. After login, store the access token and refresh token into your database
3. The access token is expire every 1 hour, so , before calling yahoo api you need to make sure access token not expire, otherwise, use refresh token to update your access token
4. So far, I test it for 4 - 5 days, it run without any problem, but I suspect the refresh token will expire, so in my program I warns the user to login again if the refresh token is expire

That's all. hope you can solve your problem

Comment: My need is i want to login japan yahoo site automatically and then i place the bid into yahoo auction. this all process are running automatically.  i have already tried oAuth. i got a token and also i got a refresh token. but how can i pass the token and bid the particular product. i unable to understand...